# Google maps Api V2 - do NOT display marker title

Tags: android

How can i NOT display the marker title when the onmarkerclick event is triggered? I saw several people saying to return false inside the event, but i am doing that and it doesnt work...
Here's my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        if (serverPush) {
            serverPush = false;
            return false;
        }

        data.getMap().moveCamera(
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(), data
                        .getMap().getCameraPosition().zoom));

        String id = marker.getTitle();
        if (id.equals(data.getUuid()) || id.equals(data.getOtherUUID())) {

        } else
            createDeleteDialog(marker, id,""+getResources().getString( R.string.delete_marker));

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    marker.hideInfoWindow(); // hides the marker title

    return true; // must return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 marker.position(latlong);
 marker.title(title);

 googleMap.addMarker(marker);
 builder.include(latlong);


 // Create Bound for camera using created builder
 LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
 // now move camera to specif bound
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
            width, height, 60));
```

Comment: if i move the camera the title will disappear?

Comment: what is you actuall requirement

Comment: I want just the title not to show when i click the marker